# How to track user browsing information on a public facing website

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, database-design, database-performance

I'm designing a public facing website that needs to track the path of users through the site. Every time the user hits the site, I need to track that information and place that path, browser, location, etc… (kinda like an analytics) into the database through several writes and also perform a couple of reads based the data that the user is browsing for. I'm worried about application performance on an enterprise level (100,000 unique visitors per day). That being said, I need to know if this is not a good strategy for this level of traffic and if there is another approach I should take to tracking this information. Doing the development work in .NET using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is done by batch-processing the IIS log files, rather than writing to the database on every page hit.

Alternatively, you can configure IIS to do the logging to the database for you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245243

Also http://forums.iis.net/t/1154908.aspx (for IIS 7)